# Simulating clicking/unclicking a bootstrap button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-4

I have the following buttons shown below that, when a user clicks on the buttons - the selected button becomes active and the previous selected button becomes unactive (much like this bootstrap example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons).

HTML:

```
<div id='button-tabset'>
        <uib-tabset>
            <uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab1" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab2" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="2" heading="Tab3" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="3" heading="Tab4" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="4" heading="Tab5" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="5" heading="Tab6" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="6" heading="Tab7" class="exampletab" id="seventhtab"></uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript, when a user performs a certain action, I have a function fired that navigates to the last tab (7th), and then makes all the tabs unactive (removes the active attribute in the class), and then makes the last tab active.

JavaScript:

```
$scope.exampleFunction = function() {
    $scope.currenttab = 'tab7';
    var header = document.getElementById("button-tabset");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("exampletab");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        if (current[0]) {
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("seventhtab").className += " active";
};
```

The issue at hand comes when we programmitcally navigate to the seventh tab, instead of a user clicking on it. The tab remains highlighted even when the user clicks away to a different tab.

The only way to 'unactive' the last tab - is to click on it (despite it being already active), simulating someone **actually** clicking on it, and then clicking away will make the tabs behave normally again.

So seems like there's a difference between programmitcally navigating and setting active to a tab vs someone manually clicking on a tab.

I've tried including `document.getElementById("seventhtab").trigger('click');` to no avail - the behavior is the same.
I feel like by selecting the tab via JavaScript, I've merely only made it 'appear' clicked - rather than a user **actually** clicking. I could use some help on what the differences could be - any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Edit:

```
<div id='button-tabset'>
    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab1" select="settab('Tab1')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab2" select="settab('Tab2')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="2" heading="Tab3" select="settab('Tab3')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="3" heading="Tab4" select="settab('Tab4')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="4" heading="Tab5" select="settab('Tab5')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="5" heading="Tab6" select="settab('Tab6')" class="exampletab"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="6" heading="Tab7" select="settab('Tab7')" class="exampletab" id="seventhtab"></uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
```

Upon second thought, I think it would help to clarify exactly how I am navigating to the tabs - upon clicking, I am sending a parameter to the settab() function and using `ng-show="currenttab === '____'` to determine which html to display (each html corresponding to each tab)

Comment: Did you try tu simulate mouseup or mouseleave?

Comment: Try ```document.getElementById("seventhtab").click()``` - HTMLElement.click() is an actual function that should get you what you need

Comment: @TomášZato I have not tried that - I'll give that a try.

Comment: @VirxEC I've tried `document.getElementById("seventhtab").click()` and `document.getElementById("seventhtab").trigger('click)` - neither of which worked :(

Comment: Wrap all of your JavaScript inside a ``window.onload = function() {/*code*/};``

Comment: @Jedo When emulating events in frameworks, sometimes you really MUST emit the events that would occur during real interaction, including hovering etc. I suggest you keep adding events until it works.